# Solution to rescue a Macbook pro 15 2016

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, mac-pro

I was trying to update my macbook pro from macOS sierra to macOS high sierra and suddenly it freezes. I tried to to restart it but all I get now is a flashing interrogation point :/

P.S. : This is my first experience with a mac.

Where i can get a fresh copy of macOS high sierra and make a bootable usb with it on a Windows PC?

Comment: Have you tried [macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314)? Hold Cmd-R or Cmd-Opt-R and reinstall that way.

Comment: Details are [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/247063/) and [there](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98600/). Just booting to recovery let’s you run disk utility, set the boot, reinstall the os without erasing your user files.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well when installing High Sierra (on day one of public release o the OS). After experiencing issues with Recovery OS as well, I took it into the Genius Bar where they were happy to help. I believe they ended up installing the OS from a recovery drive. As it was the brand new OS they had to take it overnight and contact Cupertino engineering I was told, although I would expect it to be a smooth support process by now. Best of luck getting it working quickly.